# Highlight the lineString or point in Openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

In my mapping application, I can hightlight the polygon, when mouseover it or select it, but the point and lineString cannot be highlighted, thought I add the style in script.

I found some working examples with `ol.featureOverlay` online,  but now in new openlayers3, `ol.featureOverlay` is removed from library, do some specialists know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell your interaction to read the styles from a [`function`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.style.html#.StyleFunction) of yours:

```js
var hoverInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
  style: geometryStyle
});
```

And your function will be like above:

```js
function geometryStyle(feature){
  var
    style = [],
    geometry_type = feature.getGeometry().getType(),
    white = [255, 255, 255, 1],
    blue = [0, 153, 255, 1],
    width = 6
  ;

  style['LineString'] = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: white, width: width + 2
      })
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: blue, width: width
      })
    })
  ],
  style['Polygon'] = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5] })
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: white, width: 3.5
      })
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: blue, width: 2.5
      })
    })
  ],
  style['Point'] = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: width * 2,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: blue}),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: white, width: width / 2
        })
      })
    })
  ];

  return style[geometry_type];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/prx41egk/

Comment: Thanks Jonatas, it is what i expect,  so that means only ploygon in openlayers has **default** style when highlighted, is it right ?

Comment: No, that's not right. All of them have default style, see http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.style.html

Comment: If you remove this line `style: geometryStyle` you'll see defaults.

Comment: kind of strange, in my application, the default style only works with polygon.

Comment: I got the reason, coz i add the style to lineString when i draw end, then it doest work ,when i hover on it. Do you have some way to fix it, if dont delete style from drawing end style?

Comment: Well, just don't use defaults, use `StyleFunction`.